# How to assign JavaScript variable to HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, assign

I want to assign my id variable as id to my select tag like below. How can I do it correctly?

```
var id = 0;
$('#section2').append("<div><select id='" + id + "' class='form-control' name='rendezo_neve[]' style='max-width:90%'>" + $.get("php/getElements.php", function(data) {
  $('#' + id).html(data)
}) + "</select><input type='button' value='X' class='remove_field' style='float:right;position:relative;top:-34px;right:-12px;font-size:12px;height:33px;width:33px;font-weight:bold;color:red;background-color:white;border:1px solid lightgrey;border-radius:50%'></input></div>");
```

Comment: Why do you have half a program in a single line? Use separate commands with small steps, put intermediate results in variables and you'll see that it's *way* easier to debug that, because you can closely inspect what is going on.

Comment: $.get is an asynchronous command that returns a request object, not the result string of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using this code `$('select[name=' + name + ']').attr('id', id)`. At first, select your select drop down using name & then set an ID attribute with its value.